# how to get the objects from an observable collection?

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, observablecollection

I don't know if it's possible but I would like to add objects to an observable collection and reuse them later.

I have this in wpf:

```
 <CheckBox Margin="0,9,0,5" IsChecked="{Binding Prise1.Monday, Mode=TwoWay}"/>
 <CheckBox Margin="0,10,0,5" IsChecked="{Binding Prise2.Monday, Mode=TwoWay}"/>
 <CheckBox Margin="0,10,0,5" IsChecked="{Binding Prise3.Monday, Mode=TwoWay}"/>
 <CheckBox Margin="0,9,0,0" IsChecked="{Binding Durée.Monday, Mode=TwoWay}"/>
```

For all days of the week. 
Class WeekValues :

```
    private bool _Monday;
    public bool Monday
    {
        get
        {
            return _Monday;
        }
        set
        {
            _Monday = value;
            RaisePropertyChanged(nameof(Monday));
        }
    }
    private bool _Tuesday;
    public bool Tuesday
    {
        get
        {
            return _Tuesday;
        }
        set
        {
            _Tuesday = value;
            RaisePropertyChanged(nameof(Tuesday));
        }
    }
    private bool _Wednesday;
    public bool Wednesday
    {
        get
        {
            return _Wednesday;
        }
        set
        {
            _Wednesday = value;
            RaisePropertyChanged(nameof(Wednesday));
        }
    }
    private bool _Thursday;
    public bool Thursday
    {
        get
        {
            return _Thursday;
        }
        set
        {
            _Thursday = value;
            RaisePropertyChanged(nameof(Thursday));
        }
    }
    private bool _Friday;
    public bool Friday
    {
        get
        {
            return _Friday;
        }
        set
        {
            _Friday = value;
            RaisePropertyChanged(nameof(Friday));
        }
    }
    private bool _Saturday;
    public bool Saturday
    {
        get
        {
            return _Saturday;
        }
        set
        {
            _Saturday = value;
            RaisePropertyChanged(nameof(Saturday));
        }
    }
    private bool _Sunday;
    public bool Sunday
    {
        get
        {
            return _Sunday;
        }
        set
        {
            _Sunday = value;
            RaisePropertyChanged(nameof(Sunday));
        }
    }
}
```

And i want to do something like this:

```
   public ObservableCollection<WeekValues> allPrises = new ObservableCollection<WeekValues>();

   Prise1 = new WeekValues();
   Prise2 = new WeekValues();
   Prise3 = new WeekValues();
   Durée = new WeekValues();

   allPrises.Add(Prise1);
   allPrises.Add(Prise2);
   allPrises.Add(Prise3);
   allPrises.Add(Durée);
```

And use a method like :

```
MyMethod(allPrises)
{
    foreach(var X in allPrises)
       {
           if(Prise1.Monday) ...do something
           if(Prise2.Monday) ... do something else
       }
```

Is this clear? 
So that's the idea, I'd like to know how to proceed, because when I make a foreach I only get trues / falses without "Prise1" or "Prise2". 
Would you know how to solve this?
Thank you in advance

Comment: oops, I corrected

Comment: You are iterating over all 4 `WeekValues`, aren't you? So `X` is Prise1 in the first iteration and so on. `if (Prise2.Monday)`could be written like `if (allPrises[1].Monday)` if you never change the order of the elements.

Comment: you should be using the 'x' in the foreach otherwise whats the point of using a foreach?

Comment: Thanks mm8, now it's ok. Thanks you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are iterating over all 4 `WeekValues`. So `X` is `Prise1` in the first iteration and so on.

`if (Prise2.Monday)` could be written as `if (allPrises[1].Monday)` if you never change the order of the elements.